# why the object gives "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: javascript, json, circular-reference

here    is    my    object    with    sample    data

```
Object {map: Array[10], health: 100, ai: Array[4]}
ai: Array[4]
0: THREE.Object3D
1: THREE.Object3D
2: THREE.Object3D
3: THREE.Object3D
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
health: 100
map: Array[10]
```

not    able    to    find out   why   it    gives   this    error.. anyone help??

Comment: We need to know all the references to the objects within other objects. You have a circular reference (possible a THREE.Object3D -> THREE.Object3D ref)

Answer (score 0):

One of the attributes of your object contains a reference to the object itself (or, a recursive reference to one of the sub-objects). While this works just fine, converting the object to JSON would yield infinite recursion.

Comment: @meager thanks for answering. yes it gives error during applying JSON.stringify. how can i figure this out? i used custom replacer but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dojox.json.ref` to find circular references. This code prints json representation of your `objectWithCircularReferences`:

```
require(["dojox/json/ref"], function(){
    console.log(dojox.json.ref.toJson(ko.toJS(objectWithCircularReferences)));
});
```

Any occurence of "$ref" substring in its output to console will help you locate circular references. You can alternatively pipe this json output to global variable ZZZ like this if you wish:

```
require(["dojox/json/ref"], function(){
    window.ZZZ = dojox.json.ref.toJson(ko.toJS(objectWithCircularReferences));
});
```

And of course you need to include dojo library beforehand. In an html file:

```
<script src="//yandex.st/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

In firebug console:

```
include("//yandex.st/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js")
```

In Chrome console:

```
SCRIPT = document.createElement('script');
SCRIPT.src = '//yandex.st/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js';
document.body.appendChild(SCRIPT);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is circular referece detector:

```
o = {a: 1, b:2, c:{d:3, e:4}, q:[1,2,3,4,5,{f:6,g:7}]}
o.o = o
console.log(o)
var done = []
function circRefDetec(o, path) {
   done.push(o)
   for (i in o) if (typeof o[i] == 'object') {
      if (done.indexOf(o[i]) >= 0) {
         console.log('CIRCULAR REFERECE DETECTED:', path +'.'+ i)
      } else {
         console.log(i, ':')
         circRefDetec(o[i], path +' '+ i)
      }
   }
}
circRefDetec(o, 'obj')
```

Comment: This flags "CIRCULAR REFERECE DETECTED" on every null field. Did you test this?